# strange behaviours viewDidAppear not called

Tags: ios, debugging, viewdidload, viewdidappear

I call a function to open a subview from my parent view.

I see that `viewDidLoad` is called. In my `viewDidLoad` is no code.
The strange behaviour is, that sometimes `viewDidAppear:` is not called even I have not change any code.

Of course there can be a lot of reasons, but I do not know how to debug. I am looking for a way to find out where the process hangs at the time when `viewDidLoad` is finished.

Does anyone have a hint for me or does anyone know what could be the problem? I mean sometimes it works sometime not. Is `viewDidAppear:` depending on the parentsview or is there something wrong in the subview?

```
func showSubview() {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Subview") as! SubViewController
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    //self.showViewController(vc, sender: self);
}
```

**UPDATE**
I am calling the showSubview from a async task , I guess this is not good. What do you think and how shall I do it better ? Is there any complition handler with dispatch_async ?

```
        dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, {
            dosomething_long();
            showSubview();
        })
```

**UPDATE 2**
The problem is, that I am opening the subview from a background task. I should not do this. But the question is how can I call the subview when the background task is finished. Is there any completion handler for dispatch_async call ?

**SOLVED WITH HELP OF GANDALF**

I am stupid :-) I should call the subview in the main thread:

```
        dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, {
            dosomething_long();
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                showsubview();
            });
        })
```

Comment: are you printing logs or checking this by keeping breakpoint in the method? Because if you are running in `release` mode then breakpoints may not pause the program counter as expected.

Comment: @Gandalf. I guess the problem is the debug mode as you suspected. I am developing now 1 year with xcode, but never had such a problem. When halting in the method of didappear and continuing, it failed. But it is not stopped in any of my breakpoints and I couldn't see where it stopped. Very strange. At least I am happy that the problem is not the code. I hope I will remember when I get into the same problem again. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Oh no. I just restart the app again without debug mode and it hangs again. Started the app several times without debug mode and went through. Didn't change anything, because I am just testing. I really do not understand.

Comment: Could it be that the following is the problem ? I updated my question.

Comment: UI presentation and update should be done on main thread. Check this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20590802/objective-c-trouble-updating-ui-on-main-thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20590802/objective-c-trouble-updating-ui-on-main-thread) for how to do it.

Comment: I guess updating is not the problem. I am doing this in my dosomething_long(); . But my long runner should run in background, should it not ? If yes, could the problem be, that I am open my subview from my backgroundtask ?

Comment: @Gandalf. Sorry was missunderstanding from my side. You are right. I just have to call the subview in the main thread. I will update my question. So problem is solved. Thank you very much for your help. If you like you can answer that I should call the subview in the main thread and I will accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very obvious reason for why program counter may not go inside methods is that app could be running in the `release` mode.

Now as we can see after updated question that this is not the reason and there is a UI operation happening at `background queue`.
As per iOS development guidelines all UI operation should happen on `main thread`, you should try executing that on main thread instead of a `background thread`.
Try the below code:

```
dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, {
    dosomething_long();
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {     
        showsubview();
    });
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is; is the view created before? Is it caused when you reopen your app from background?
You can check the lifecycle from here and I think your problem is occurred because of that.
[iOS 7 - Difference between viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22214843/ios-7-difference-between-viewdidload-and-viewdidappear)