# UITableViewController doesn't populate - Data should be available

Tags: ios, swift2, alamofire, swifty-json

So I've have been trying to populate a TableViewController with some `JSON data` from the internet. The TableViewController just doesn't show the data. I've debugged and tried to trace my constants & vars as much as possible to see if I got bad data, but the data seems ok.

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON
import Alamofire

class TableController: UITableViewController  {

    var TableData:Array < Datenstruktur > = Array < Datenstruktur>()

    let serverURL = "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/"

    struct Datenstruktur{
        var name:String?
        var email:String?

        init(add: NSDictionary){
            name = add["name"] as? String
            email = add["email"] as? String
        }

    }

    @IBOutlet var tableview: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //tableview.dataSource = self
        //tableview.delegate = self

        get_data_from_server(serverURL)

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }
```

So this would be a struct I've created for my TableData as well as my viewDidLoad() which basically just calls a function `get_data_from_server(serevrURL)`.

Following up are my tableView functions

```
   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return TableData.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) //as! UITableViewCell

        let data = TableData[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = data.name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = data.email

        return cell
    }
```

In my `func get_data_from_server()` I'm using the latest Alamofire framework to GET the json from the server. Since I'm also using SwiftyJSON the received JSON is parsed and used within another func call, where the Data should actually be populated `extract_json()`

```
    func do_table_refresh()
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.tableview.reloadData()
            return
        })
    }

    func get_data_from_server(url:String)
    {
        Alamofire.request(.GET, url).validate().responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .Success:
                if let value = response.result.value {
                    let json = JSON(value)

                    self.extract_json(json)

                }
            case .Failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }

    }

    func extract_json(data:JSON)
    {


        let jsonData: JSON = data

        var namesDictionary: Dictionary<String, String> = [:]

        for var i = 0; i < jsonData["contacts"].count ; i++ {
            print(i)

            namesDictionary["name"] = jsonData["contacts"][i]["name"].stringValue
            namesDictionary["email"] = jsonData["contacts"][i]["name"].stringValue
            TableData.append(Datenstruktur(add: namesDictionary))

        }

        //do_table_refresh()

        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I also got a do_table_refresh() to reload the data for the tableview - but when I try to use it I get a `Thread1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC...`

I also tried to `print(TableData)` and I've seen that there actually IS Data inside, but its Optional .. Do I have to unwrap it or something? I kind of got a feeling that my code is almost OK.. well at least as far as I can trace the data :D

*FYI:* I'm actually new to Swift,also I have not any experience with ObjectiveC - but I got a C,C++ and Java background...

Help would be much appreciated 
Thanks!

EDIT:
I got it fixed!
After adding this inside my Alamofire.request ( inside `get_data_from_server()` ) my TableView populated with data.

```
        if self.TableData.count > 0 {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
```

so my `get_data_from_server()` now looks like this:

```
func get_data_from_server(url:String)
{
    Alamofire.request(.GET, url).validate().responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .Success:
            if let value = response.result.value {
                let json = JSON(value)
                self.extract_json(json)

                if self.TableData.count > 0 {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        case .Failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }

}
```

Since I have not used the `do_table_refresh()` I guess I will delete it. I've read somewhere that my Alamofire request doesn't end up in this dispatch queue anyway. So my question would be why is that so? and what does actually end up in that queue, so when does it make sense to use `dispatch_asynch(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{})` ?

Comment: Can you add a sample code in github? so we can help you better.

Comment: yes I've just uploaded it! 
https://github.com/b101/DevTest/tree/master/ClosestStoreageroom

Comment: I got it ! :) I had to use a `self.tableView.reloadData()` inside my Alamofire call. After that my Table was being populated. Since I found no use for the `do_table_refresh()` function I will delete it I guess. I've read that Alamofire isn't anyway in this `dispatch_asynch(dispatch_get_main_queue()` but why is that? and what actually IS in this queue?

Comment: b101, You can only update your UI from the main thread. dispatch_asynch(dispatch_get_main_queue() is part of the code that gets the main queue so you can update the UI. That's covered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20590802/objective-c-trouble-updating-ui-on-main-thread or google "ios update ui main thread"

Comment: @xdeleon thank you, if there is a main queue does that mean that there is also some kind of "sub" queue? How do I know when and which part of my program code is within the main / sub queue? The Answer from the Link you provided used `dispatch_asynch(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0)` did he put the following code inside the main queue by calling this function?

Comment: Your app runs in a threaded environment. Where all the different pieces of code are broken up into different pieces (threads). If all your code ran in a single threat the app would be slow and unresponsive. UI updates happen on their own thread to prevent that. These links might help: http://iosdevelopmentjournal.com/blog/2013/01/16/forcing-things-to-run-on-the-main-thread/, http://blog.grio.com/2014/04/understanding-the-ios-main-thread.html